# Creating a ReverseProxy using Apache and VirtualHost

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get a reverse proxy set up on Apache, but I'm having some trouble getting it working using `VirtualHost`.  All I need to do is proxy requests for `/test` to local port `8000`.  The following .conf entries works fine:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/test" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

But when I throw `VirtualHost` into the mix, the proxy doesn't work.
Following is how I'm trying to achieve the reverse proxy using `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/test" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm running Apache v2.4.5 on CentOS 7.3.  All of this config is in a separate file in Apache's `conf.d` folder.

Comment: Do you have a 'default' VirtualHost, which is getting selected in preference to your configured VirtualHost?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add this within VirtualHost:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Other reasons may be: first virtual host directive "overlapping" settings for subsequent virtual hosts.

Comment: That didn't seem to help :/ no change

Comment: Don't use this config! This is a forward proxy - not what you want.